# Isometries of hyper-Kähler manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, holonomy, hyperkaehler

For the purposes of this question, a hyper-Kähler manifold will be a complete connected Riemannian manifold $(\mathcal{M},g)$ whose holonomy representation is isomorphic to the natural representation of the compact symplectic group $Sp_n$.

There is a $3$-dimensional real representation naturally associated to such a space. This can be given by the action of the isometry group permuting the holonomy subbundles within their common $Sp_nSp_1$-enlargement, or equivalently by rotating the $2$-sphere of parallel complex structures. This is summarized in the exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
Tri(\mathcal{M},g) \to Isom(\mathcal{M},g) \stackrel{\phi}\to SO(Im \mathbb{H})
\end{equation*}
where the middle entry is the isometry group and on the left are the isometries that preserve all complex structures (*tri-holomorphic*). I would like to know about the representation $\phi$.

A Killing vector field on a compact Ricci-flat space is parallel. Therefore, provided the dimension is larger than one, the isometry group of a locally-irreducible compact Ricci-flat space is discrete. It is furthermore finite by compactness.

The finite subgroups of $SO_3$ are known to be of various forms: cyclic groups, dihedral groups, and the rotation groups of a regular tetrahedron, octahedron/cube and icosahedron/dodecahedron.

[image: Commercial Photography][image: Commercial Photography][image: Commercial Photography][image: Commercial Photography][image: Commercial Photography]

(Fundamental domains of $C_4$, $D_4$ and the three polyhedral subgroups, images from Wikipedia.)

**Q)** Are examples known of compact hyper-Kähler manifolds that realise all of these types of subgroup through $\phi$?

I would appreciate any related remarks, as I have not been able to deduce much from the examples of compact hyper-Kähler manifolds that I have seen.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking.  When $\mathcal{M}$ is compact and $g$ is a hyperKähler metric on $\mathcal{M}$, the isometry group is finite (not merely discrete) since it must be compact in the compact open topology and have the structure of a Lie group of dimension $0$, so the image of $\phi$ must be finite as well.

Comment: @RobertBryant, yes of course, I should have noticed that. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: "It is a well-known fact that the isometry group of a compact Ricci-flat space is finite": this is false, take for example a compact flat torus.

Comment: @YangMills, I ought to be more careful with my well-known 'facts'. I'll fix it now.

Comment: I don't understand $\phi$. You take an isometry $F$ of a compact manifold $M$ and you map to a quaternionic matrix $A=\phi(F)$, apparently. What is this $\phi$?

Comment: @BenMcKay, I see the confusion coming from the notation $SO(Im \mathbb{H})$. By this I mean the group of rotations of the $3$-dim real vector space $Im \mathbb{H}$ spanned by the parallel complex structures, not something whose entries lie in $Im \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: OK, I see now. So the vector space $\operatorname{Im}\mathbb{H}$ is the span of the 3 complex structures.